# How to 'hammer' click in cypress.io?

Tags: cypress

I am running with Chrome 74 and am wanting to write a test that will 'spam' click a counter.

Is there any way to write it so it will click `x` times instead of writing this over and over:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=click-up]').click()
```

I asked in the Cypress Gitter and someone had responded with:

> Providing that your selector matches n+ Dom elements, its going to
>   click all of em
>
> ```js
> cy.get(selector).click({multiple: true})
> ```

But this does not work in my problem.

If I could I'd share direct code but I am under an NDA.

### Solution

So, I took jon's comment and yes a for loop works to re-create that 'spam' click.

Example:

```js
describe('increase the counter', () => {
  it('spam click by 10', () => {
    for(let n = 0; n < 10; n ++){
      cy.get('[data-cy=click-up]').click()
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: `multiple` is for clicking multiple different elements matching the same selector, not the same element multiple times. It's just JavaScript, so maybe `for (let n = 0; n < x; n++) { cy.get('[data-cy=click-up]').click() }`?

Comment: thank you! Appreciate the help

Comment: Please add the solution as answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

So, I took jon's comment and yes a for loop works to re-create that 'spam' click.

Example:

```js
describe('increase the counter', () => {
  it('spam click by 10', () => {
    for(let n = 0; n < 10; n ++){
      cy.get('[data-cy=click-up]').click()
    }
  })
})
```